# How to send or write data for proxying protocol

Tags: java, sockets, https, proxy, socks

I am trying to write data for proxying protocol but in **java.net.SocksSocketImpl** and **java.net.HttpConnectSocketImpl** we don't have write methods like :-

*public int write(ByteBuffer paramByteBuffer) throws IOException*

*public long write(ByteBuffer[] paramArrayOfByteBuffer, int paramInt1, int paramInt2) throws IOException*

the way we have in **sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl** class

Please suggest me how can i do write operation using the proxying classes .